# Django intersection of two query sets on similar attribute

Tags: python, django, django-queryset, set-theory

I have two models in django, im not sure how to write them (whether to have an abstract model and inherit etc... or have two different models) but generally I have two types of objects A and B.

A and B are exactly the same as they are just items. They both have the following attributes:

name, price

Now I want to compare all *similar* items in A and B (similar items are items which have the ***same name***) and see the difference in prices between them (note: assume no duplicates, but assume that the intersection contains items that may not be in A or B or both, meaning A and B are not identical sets of data so A may have 20 items but B might have 643)

How do I do this in Django using models etc...

Comment: how do you define "common items in A and B" ?

Comment: Apologies, I have updated the original post, basically similar/common items, are items which have the same name. So in Set A, if I have a item (name="apple") and in Set B I have another item (name="apple") then there are similar. Their prices might differ so I would need to compare a.price and b.price. The first thing I want is the common items in A and B, and then their price differences..

Comment: A and B both have a price, they sound like products in a shop... is there any case where you would want to list or search across 'all products' ? i.e. not always 'just A' products or 'just B' products but sometimes to treat them as the same thing

Comment: Yes, you can assume that there are different vendors who sell the exact same products, but different prices. So ShopA has item "macbook" and Shop B also has the exact same macbook. So I want to compare their prices. But the thing here is I want the full set, so I want all comparison for all products that are common between shop A and B

Answer (score 2):

From your comment I think you only want a single model, with a `vendor` field to distinguish between them

```
class Product(models.Model):
    VENDOR_CHOICES = (
        ('a', 'Vendor A'),
        ('b', 'Vendor B')
    )
    # you may find it more appropriate to have a ForeignKey to
    # a Vendor model instead of this choice field:
    vendor = models.CharField(max_length=16, choices=VENDOR_CHOICES)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2)
```

Then you can get the price difference between any two vendors (Django 1.8):

```
from django.db.models import Func, F

prices = (
    Product.objects
    .filter(vendor__in=('a', 'b'))
    .order_by('name', 'vendor')  # order rows within each group
    .values('name')  # GROUP BY `name`
    .annotate(
        first_vendor_price=Func(F('price'), function='FIRST'),
        second_vendor_price=Func(F('price'), function='LAST')
    )
)

price_diffs = {
    group['name']: group['first_vendor_price'] - group['second_vendor_price']
    for group in prices
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason you don't annotate the difference?

Comment: Either it didn't occur to me or Django's expression system wasn't able to when I wrote this answer. But yes that would be a good idea!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is exactly what you're asking but I can think of two approaches to query on the shared field.

*Option 1*

First up, you can get a single QuerySet with objects of both model types by using model inheritance.

**Code:**

```
class ModelBase(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    price = models.FloatField()

class ModelA(ModelBase):
    field_a = models.BooleanField()

class ModelB(ModelBase):
    field_b = models.BooleanField()
```

**Testing it out:**

> In [4]: from test_app.models import ModelA, ModelB, ModelBase
>
> In [5]: matches = ModelBase.objects.filter(name='Product1')
>
> In [6]: matches.count()
>
> Out[6]: 2
>
> In [7]: for m in matches:
>
> ...:     print "%s - %s" % (m.name, m.price)
>
> ...:
>
> Product1 - 10.5
>
> Product1 - 3.5

*Option 2*

Alternatively, if you don't want inheritance and don't mind evaluating the entire QuerySet you can use itertools.

**Code**

```
class ModelX(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    price = models.FloatField()
    field_x = models.BooleanField()

class ModelY(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    price = models.FloatField()
    field_y = models.BooleanField()
```

**Testing it out**

> from test_app.models import ModelX, ModelY
>
> from itertools import chain
>
> full_set = chain(ModelX.objects.filter(name='Product2'), Model.Y.objects.filter(name='Product2'))
>
> In [5]: full_set = chain(ModelX.objects.filter(name='Product2'), > ModelY.objects.filter(name='Product2'))
>
> In [6]: for m in full_set:
>
> ...:     print "%s - %s" % (m.name, m.price)
>
> ...:
>
> Product2 - 14.0
>
> Product2 - 30.0

Comment: Option 1 is exactly what I'm looking for except I need to apply this line

matches = ModelBase.objects.filter(name='Product1')

Across all products 

and do the same price comparison for each via iterating over them.

So I'm looking for a set intersection between Set A and Set B which only have common products and I want to iterate over them... Something like this list 

[
   [{'name':'apple', 'price':1.99}, {'name':'apple', 'price':2.49}],
   [{'name':'orange', 'price':13.99}, {'name':'orange', 'price':12.49}],
   [{'name':'pear', 'price':6.99}, {'name':'pear', 'price':7.49}]
]

Comment: Calculate the intersection set first, then pass it to the filter function using __in.

Answer (score 0):

I would go with an abstract class, and implement a polymorphic relationship; querying via Django's ContentType Framework.

This solution assumes that `Model A` has attributes that distinguish itself from `Model B`, otherwise a single model with a `ChoiceField` would be most appropriate.

### Polymorphism in Django

```
    ModelManager(models.Manager):
        def get_intersection_on_name_for(self, name):
            model = Model.objects.filter(model_object__name=name).distinct()
            return model


    Model(models.Model):
        content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, null=True)
        object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True)
        model_object = generic.GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id') # this gets the actual field obj

        objects = ModelManager()


    ModelBase(models.Model):
        name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
        price = models.CharField(max_length=255)

        class Meta:
            abstract = True

    ModelA(ModelBase):
        weight = models.CharField(max_length=255)


    ModelB(ModelBase):
        url = models.UrlField(max_length=255)
```

In use:

```
    name = "Test Name"
    Model.objects.get_intersection_on_name_for(name)
```

---

### References:

**Polymorphism**:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_(computer_science)

**Subtype Polymorphism**:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subtyping

**Django ContentTypes Framework**: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/contenttypes/

**Django Custom Managers**:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/managers/

**Django Queryset `.distinct()`**: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.distinct

For more powerful polymorphism in django take a look at [django-polymorphic](https://github.com/chrisglass/django_polymorphic).

Comment: in terms of performance, would this solution work the fastest, compared to the solutions below?

Comment: @user3413046 this is a good answer, it's a better version of dwightgunning 'option 1'. However they are both going to be slower than the 'single model' option I suggested since you have to join across the separate model tables... I'd advise to avoid this approach unless you _really_ need A and B products to have very different behaviour.

Comment: This solution does do a join operation, which is inherently slower than doing an operation on a single table. With that said, you're probably not going to notice an issue with speed here without significant scale.    


@Anentropic does mention the issue of this potentially not being the answer to your problem; he is re-iterating the disclaimer from my second paragraph.